# How would I use BASH (mac) to find mouse pointer location?

Tags: bash, macos, scripting

So I can't load outside software, as this is a script for testing new mac workstations as they are set up, and the script logs pass/fail/null (skipped) state of each test.  I have everything complete except mouse movement.  Because this is for work, the setup techs have to run this script, and they do not have superuser privileges, and it needs to be carried around on a USB drive.   Is this possible?

Edit for details:

I have multiple workstations that are being tested by techs as they walk around and hook up their machines to the docks.  It tests internal and external networks, as well as keyboard mouse and sound. I have the keyboard and network stuff.  I am still learning how to use the text-to-speech engine to play a sound, and ask the user if it played.  All of the data up to this point is written as a variable, and then saved to a csv.  I am still working on the writing to csv part as I am working with management on how they want data to be displayed.

TLDR Tech moves mouse and I need to check if the mouse was moved in the script and write pass/fail

below is the code I have (slightly modified to retain privacy)

```
#!/bin/bash

#this pulls the logged in user's name.
runninguser=$(whoami)
#end of line


#script version
scrver="script version 0.0.1"
#end script version

#welcome text
echo Welcome to the Mac Install Test Script, by [ME].  This is $scrver
#end welcome text

# this section is what makes the directory where the files will
# be temporarily saved to.

mkdir -p ~/tmp


#this section asks for tech's last name and first name
echo Hi $runninguser, I am the Mac Automated Test Script.  Nice to meet you!




# This section is for getting the customer name
echo "What is your customer's last name for this workstation?"
read custLname
echo "Thank you, now what is your customer's first name?"
read custFname




# This section is for testing to see if the internet connection works.

echo "Now we are going to test the external network connection."

curl -o ~/tmp/elgoogs http://www.google.com


testout1=~/tmp/elgoogs

if grep -q "/body"  "$testout1"
then echo  "pass" && internettest="PASS"
else echo "fail" && internettest="FAIL"
fi

#this section is for testing the internal network  connection

curl -o ~/tmp/[REDACTED] http://[REDACTED].gov

testin1=~tmp/[REDACTED]

if grep -q "/body" "$testin1"
then echo "pass" && intranettest="PASS"
else echo "fail" && intranettest="FAIL"
fi



#The next section is for keyboard testing
echo "We are now going to test the keyboard"
sleep 2

echo "Please press the enter key!"

while true; do
read -rsn1 kinput
if [ "$kinput" = “” ]; then
    echo "keyboard test passed!" && kbtest="PASS"  && break
fi
done











#                        VARIABLES & STRINGS
#
#       testout1         is filepath for internet test
#       internettest     is the pass/fail state for outside network testing.
#       runninguser      is the currently running user
#       scver            is the version of the script being run
#       custLname        is the Customer's Last Name
#       custFname        is the Customer's First Name
#       testin1          is the intranet test
#       intranettest     is the pass/fail state for inside network testing.
#       kinput           is the input variable, what is being waited for.
#       kbtest           is the pass/fail state for keyboard test
#
```

Comment: There's nothing built into bash itself that's useful for the job, or even *available for* bash in a sense that would have it not be similarly available for any other language able to start subprocesses and read their output.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  How would you propose moving forward?

Comment: A good place to start would be providing enough detail that someone can figure out what you actually want. Do you have a user operating the mouse and you're trying to figure out if it works? A script that's supposed to emulate a device and you're trying to figure out if *that* works? Be specific about what you're trying to accomplish, and *less* specific about what tools you want to use to get there (so someone can advise the best tool for the job, as opposed to the one that best fits your preconception of what a solution will look like).

Comment: There, I added the code (slightly modified to retain privacy) and a tldr.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Gotcha. Short form: You're better off using AppleScript rather than bash.

Comment: what is apple script and how hard is it to learn?

Comment: See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript), or [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html).

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.  We shall see how this turns out. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than telling the user to move the mouse and trying to read its position, it might be easier to pop up a dialog asking them to move the mouse and click `OK` which will equally prove it works. You could also tell the user to use TAB and Enter to select `Cancel` if the mouse doesn't work.

So, from `bash`

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Mouse over OK button and click it, or use TAB and Enter to select Cancel if mouse does not work" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"}'
```

Here is a slightly different example, with `PASS` and `FAIL` buttons and also a title and which captures the result in a `bash`variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

#this pulls the logged in user's name.
runninguser=$(whoami)
#end of line

...
...
# Test mouse responds

result=$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Mouse over PASS button and click it, or use TAB and Enter to select FAIL if mouse does not work" with title "Mouse Test" buttons {"FAIL", "PASS"} default button 1')

echo $result
button returned:PASS
```

[image]

Comment: +1; that said -- is the selection reflected in exit status? How should the calling bash program read the result of the AppleScript segment?

Comment: I'll add details and screenshots later when I get home.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I started rewriting in Applescript, but of course, it's all new to me so it is taking a bit longer than i'd like.  I think version 0.0.1 will use the BASH workaround, and the next build I push will be the applescript version.

Comment: Well i'm back... forgot to say that this worked excellently.  Thanks much!